# Refactoring my route to be more dynamic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Currently my URL structure is like this:

www.example.com/honda/
www.example.com/honda/add
www.example.com/honda/29343

I have a controller named HondaController.

Now I want to refactor this so I can support more car manufacturers.
The database has a table that stores all the manufacturers that I want to support.

How can I keep my URL like above, but now support:

www.example.com/ford
www.example.com/toyota/add
etc.

I can easily rename the HondaController to CarController, and just pass in the string 'honda' or 'toyota' and my controller will work (it is hard coded to 'honda' right now).

**Is this possible?  I'm not sure how how to make a route dynamic based on what I have in the database.**

Answer (score 3):

Any part of your route can be dynamic just be making it into a route parameter. So instead of "/honda/{action}", do:

```
/{manufacturer}/{action}
```

This will give you a parameter called "manufacturer" that was passed to your action method.  So your action method signature could now be:

```
public ActionResult add(string manufacturer) { }
```

It would be up to you to verify that the manufacturer parameter correctly matched the list of manufacturers in the database - it would probably be best to cache this list for a quicker lookup.

---

**Updated**: What I mean by "you have to take out the default parameters" for the default route is this.  If you have:

```
route.MapRoute("Default", "/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                new { id = 1 }    // <-- this is the parameter default
              );
```

then this route will match any url with two segments, as well as any url with three segments.  So "/product/add/1" will be handled by this route, but so will "/product/add".
If you take out the `"new { id = 1 }"` part, it will only handle URL's that look like "/product/add/1".

Comment: womp, but won't that conflict with the default route?  

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { action = "Index", id = ""}  // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: It doesn't really conflict, but it would take precedence.  Always map your most specific routes first - so map your {controller}/{action}/{id} route before /{manufacturer}/{action}/.  This gives the default route a chance to match the URL first.  Also note that you can always do away with the default route if you're not using it.

Comment: Note you would have to take out the default parameters ;)

Comment: what do you mean take the default parameters out?

Comment: @homestead - I updated my answer to address your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

i have made something like this for granite as i wanted to have a material controller  but have a url like so:

black/granite/worktops
black/quartz/worktops

etc

i did this route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Quote", "quote/{color}/{surface}/{type}",
                        new {controller = "Quote", action = "surface"});
```

swap quote for car so u can have:

car/honda/accord

your route can then be

```
routes.MapRoute("cars", "car/{make}/{model}",
                        new {controller = "Cars", action = "Index"});
```

your actionResults can then look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string make, string model)
    {
        //logic here to get where make and model

        return View();
    }
```

that i think covers it

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is instead using:

```
domain/m/<manufacturer>/<action>
```

Where 'm' is the manufacturer controller. This will allow you to use the same controller for all of your extensions and save you a lot of headache in the future, especially when adding new features. Using a one-letter controller is often times desirable when you want to retain your first variable ( in this case) as the first point of interest.